# I want to see if this claim is true

Tags: real-analysis

I want to see if this claim is true:

**For each real number $w$ there exist real numbers $a,b,c$ such that  $w=a(b/c)$** where $c≠0$

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on $a$ or $b$?

Comment: Let $a=w{{{}}}$.

Comment: ... and $b = c \ne 0$.

Comment: Either it is true and trivial (e.g. a,b,c real) or it is wrong (a,b,c rationals).

Comment: I would assume that you forgot some restriction,and probably b/c are coprime integers

Comment: @GitGud: I have edited the question.

Comment: @DER It's the same. Take $a = w$ and any $b = c \ne 0$. For example: $\pi\sqrt{5} = \pi\sqrt{5}(10/10)$.

Comment: @DER the solution $w=a$, $b=c=1$ still holds, except if you mean something special by $x(y)$

Comment: @AthanagorWurlitzer: I mean the product. So the claim is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example
$$ab=c\cdot\omega \lor (a=\omega \land b=c\not=0)$$